# Why are plugin settings not all nested in one place?

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

Through my modest usages of WordPress, i have encountered many plugins.

Some of them have menus displaying at the bottom of the menu panel, some are inserted within the menu panel as if they were WP native, and some are hidden away in the settings tab.

My question is in two parts :

1 - What are the historical reasons for this variety ?

2 - Is it seen by the WP team as something that should / will be fixed ?

It feels confusing to new users !

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress team doesn't have anything to do with it. The plugin authors decide where to hook in their menus. As such, there really isn't anything that can be done to unify them into one location.